# If $rank(A) = rank(B)$ and $rank(A^2) = rank(B^2)$ then $A$ is similar to $B$

Tags: linear-algebra

For which $n$ we have:

If $rank(A) = rank(B)$ and $rank(A^2) = rank(B^2)$ then $A$ is similar to $B$. Assume also that $A,B$ are of dimension $n$ and that $A,B$ are nilpotent with the same nilpotence index $m$. I've tried finding jordan form information, diagonalization, but didn't get too far.

Comment: Are you sure this statement is correct?

Comment: @Shaq They seem to be asking: "Let $A$ and $B$ be $(n \times n)$-matrices, which are nilpotent with the same nilpotence index $m$. Moreover, suppose that the ranks of $A$ and $B$  and the ranks of $A^2$ and $B^2$ coincide. For which $n$ are $A$ and $B$ necessarily similar?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a start:

The nilpotence index tells you the size of the largest Jordan block.
The rank tells you how many blocks there are, and together with the rank of the square
tells you how many blocks of size $1$.  Let's say there are $b$ blocks of which $b_1$ are of size $1$, and the largest block has size $m$.  The question then is whether there is more than one way to partition $n - b_1 - m$ into $b - b_1 - 1$ blocks, each of size from $2$ to $m$.

Comment: Sir , you say rank tells the number of blocks ,, if for suppose we take a $4\times 4$ nilpotent matrix with only one non zero element (e.g. taking $1$ at the $a_{14}$ th position) , then rank is only $1$ ,,but blocks are $3$ in count.

Comment: Yes, for an $n \times n$ matrix with $b$ blocks for eigenvalue $0$, the rank will be $n-b$.  Here $4-3 = 1$.